# Using hierarchical select to display a particular section of content

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have a content type called "Results" that displays the results of a particular game.  I am using the Hierarchical select module for my taxonomy terms that include Year, Game and League.

My goal is to create a view that only displays a Result content type that matches the terms selected in the exposed Hierarchical Select module.  I currently have the view working, but it is displaying all the Results content type.

Comment: Drupal 6 views 6.x?

Comment: Have u added the exposed filter using hierarchal select?

Comment: Yes the filter is exposed.  It displays what I have selected first, then all other Results content after that.  I thought about limiting the display, but each game has a different number of results so that is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

As far as drupal 6 views 6.x is concerned. You need to ensure you are saving the taxonomy heirarchy as additional terms in the database. Ensure also you are saving the entire lineage from the view. Finally Add a filter with Taxonomy: Term ID and leave this using default values.

(1) Ensuring you are saving the taxonomy heirarchy as additional terms:

-edit your "Results" content type, go to manage fields and edit the heirarchical field. Somewhere on this page you will see 'Save values additionally to the core taxonomy system (into the 'term_node' table).'

(2) Ensure you are saving the entire lineage:

-on the same page as above follow the link to oonfigure this heirarchical select on a separate window.. 'Due to limitations of CCK, there is a separate form to configure this Hierarchical Select widget's settings'

(3) Go back to views and add that filter I mentioned above.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming I need to enable the Hierarchical Select Content Taxonomy part of the module to do what you have listed above?

Comment: you are correct. BTW, is that a YEAR -> Game -> League structure? (League under Game under Year?)

Comment: Yes that is the correct structure.

Comment: It's most probably because drupal cannot find references of these terms in the additional table relating to the node. As a result, it will show you all of them. You can verify this by looking at the term_node table.

Comment: I am updating my content to include the Content Tax, I will let you know how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: Ok...I have tried what was posted and it did not generate the results I wanted.  How do look up the term_node table from your previous post?

Comment: jnroche - I should have said this earlier - Thank you.

Comment: the term_node table, check it directly from your phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Checked the term_node.  honestly I am not sure I know what I am looking at.  There is a term_data that includes all the taxonomy I have on the site.  Each entry has a TID number.  Then within the term_hierarchy those same TID number show the parent. So it appears that everything is copying over.

Comment: Are you sure the terms are saved with their corresponding nodes? And in the exposed filter did you select Taxonomy : Term ID (with depth)Your settings should be the right vocabulary and choose heirarchical select selection type with Depth = 0...

Comment: Using Term ID with depth.  If I go into the content and click on one of the Taxonomy terms it does provide me with all content related to that term.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong with your views? In the term_node table can you verify if when saving a new results content type data are you sure this table gets populated with 3 new items?